# jQuery: Data is not loaded: ERR_FAILED / ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR / ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, nginx, https, http2

I'm running an Enterprise Resource Planing program served by NGINX with data loading by jQuery.

After coming back from holiday, the program doesn't work anymore as expected. The data itself isn't being loaded anymore.

Within my holidays the server updated some packages, but even when i downgrade them to previous version, the error exists.

Database is up and running, because without i can't even log in. Disabling firewalls makes no changes to the problem. Even updating jQuery from prior used original version `jQuery-3.4.1` to `jQuery-3.6.0` doesn't make any difference. Storage (space) is available too.

A fresh plain installation of the software itself makes no differences as well. Same error.

**Any hints how to solve that?**

I'm not that familar with jQuery.

[image]

[image]

Comment: At line no 3919 in the second image, I think you are trying to you check conditions instead of passing the parameters. Seems the data you are passing is not compatible. Ascertain, the data you are trying to pass. You should share your Code chunk for help you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is, i don't have a code chunk itself, because this software is from a different company. Sounds like it might be related to MySQL where the data is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

I messed up with the buffer values of nginx.conf and set them back to the default values.

After that, all works fine again.
Crazy, because these values was set for years.